# Can I use the possessive to indicate the origin of products?

Tags: expressions

Suppose an apple is produced in a place called Gotham. Can I call it Gotham's apple to indicate the place of its orign?  I guess it is natural to call it an apple from Gotham or a Gotham apple by using the proper noun as an adjectve.
I understand that salmon caught in Alaska are usually called Alaskan salmon or Alaska salmon. But I have spotted on the Internet Alaska's salmon.

Comment: If the name is that of the producer then it would seem appropriate to use a possessive, e.g. *MacDonald's hamburgers*, *Collins' Dictionary*. But if the descriptor is the name of a place, then we wouldn't normally use the possessive, but the place name sometimes adjectivally, but not always: e.g. New Zealand apples, Argentine beef, Australian wheat, French wines,  Japanese sushi, Scottish salmon etc.